# How to make a 3D Model's outline drop shadows?

Tags: rendering, modifiers, objects, armature, compositing-nodes

Can anyone tell me how to make 3D Models' outline drop shadows?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable Transparent Film under `Render Properties > Film > Transparent`

[image]

1. HSV node to make B/W.
2. Blur node to soften edges of shadow.
3. Translate node to offset shadow. In my case 5px right and 10px down.
4. Set Alpha node to reduce opacity.

All of above nodes can be tweaked to your liking. I have used an Alpha Over with a blue colour for a background, but this could easily be an image with an Image Texture / Image Sequence node, or even another View Layer.

[image]